# box() for plots in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to put a box around my plot output but when I add box() I receive the following:
Error in box(plotlyOutput("tempplot")) : plot.new has not been called yet. Not sure how else I could approach this?

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
source("simulated_annealing.R")
```

UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Simulated Annealing App"),
mainPanel(strong("SYSTEM OUTPUTS"),
            box(plotlyOutput("tempplot"))
         ))
```

SERVER:

```
server <- function(input,output)
{
output$tempplot <- renderPlotly({input$Go

    Func <- as.character(input$ObjectiveFun)
    
    if(as.numeric(input$maxormin == 2))
    {
      Func <- paste("-(", Func, ")", sep="", collapse="")
    }
    
    value <- simannealing(Func,as.numeric(input$TEMP),as.numeric(input$NITER),as.numeric(input$AMIN),alpha <- as.double(input$ALPHA),as.numeric(input$NEPOCHS),as.numeric(input$XL),as.numeric(input$XU),as.numeric(input$YL),as.numeric(input$YU))
    
    tempdata <- data.frame(x = 1:length(value[[4]]),y = value[4])
    plot_ly(tempdata,x = ~tempdata[ ,1],y = ~tempdata[ ,2],type = "scatter",mode = "markers", marker = list(size = 5, color = "red")) %>%
      layout(title = "Temperature change", xaxis = list(title = "Number of iterations"), yaxis = list(title = "Temperature"))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: There is no `box()` function in the three packages that you load at the start of your script. Did you maybe forget to load the shinydashboard package? Without a reproducible example it is hard to help. My guess is that your code is calling `graphics::box()` and this throws the error you are seeing. But probably you want a different `box()` function.

Comment: The base R `box()` function uses the base graphic device, plotly uses javascript to draw graphs, you cannot use base plot function on a plotly graph.

Comment: @TimTeaFan I was unaware of this but that makes sense. Thanks for the info :)